# Sturm-Liouville Questions (2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In thinking about Sturm-Liouville theory a bit I see I have no actual idea what is going on.

The first issue I have is that my book began with the statement that given

$$L[y] = a(x)y'' + b(x)y' + c(x)y = f(x)$$

the problem $L[y] \ = \ f$ can be re-cast in the form $L[y] \ = \ \lambda y$.

Now it could be a typo on their part but I see no justification for the way you can just do that!

More importantly though is the motivation for Sturm-Liouville theory in the first place. The story as I know it is as follows:

Given a linear second order ode

$$F(x,y,y',y'') = L[y] = a(x)y'' + b(x)y' + c(x)y = f(x)$$

it is an exact equation if it is derivable from a differential equation of one order lower, i.e.

$$F(x,y,y',y'') = \frac{d}{dx}g(x,y,y').$$

The equation is exact iff

$$a''(x) - b'(x) + c(x) = 0. $$

If $F$ is not exact it can be made exact on multiplication by a suitable integrating factor $\alpha(x)$.

This equation is exact iff

$$(\alpha(x)a(x))'' - (\alpha(x)b(x))' + \alpha(x)c(x) = 0 $$

If you expand this out you get the Adjoint operator

$$L^*[\alpha(x)] \ = \ (\alpha(x)a(x))'' \ - \ (\alpha(x)b(x))' \ + \ \alpha(x)c(x) \ = 0 $$

If you expand $L^*$ you see that we can satisfy $L \ = \ L^*$ if $a'(x) \ = \ b(x)$ & $a''(x) \ = \ b'(x)$ which then turns $L[y]$ into something of the form

$$L[y] \ = \ \frac{d}{dx}[a(x)y'] \ + \ c(x)y \ = \ f(x).$$

Thus we seek an integratiing factor $\alpha(x)$ so that we can satisfy this & the condition this will hold is that $\alpha(x) \ = \ \frac{1}{a(x)}e^{\int\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}dx}$

Then we're dealing with:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\alpha(x)a(x)y'] \ + \ \alpha(x)c(x)y \ = \ \alpha(x)f(x)$$

But again, by what my book said they magically re-cast this problem as

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\alpha(x)a(x)y'] \ + \ \alpha(x)c(x)y \ = \ \lambda \alpha(x) y(x)$$

Then calling

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\alpha(x)a(x)y'] \ + \ ( \alpha(x)c(x)y \ - \ \lambda \alpha(x) )y(x) \ = \ 0$$

a Sturm-Liouville problem.

My question is, how can I make sense of everything I wrote above? How can I clean it up & interpret it, like at one stage I thought we were turning our 2nd order ode into something so that it reduces to the derivative of a first order ode so we can easily find first integrals then the next moment we're pulling out eigenvalues & finding full solutions - what's going on? I want to be able to look at $a(x)y'' \ + \ b(x)y' \ + \ c(x)y \ = \ f(x)$ & know how & why we're turning this into a Sturm-Liouville problem in a way that makes sense of exactness & integrating factors, thanks for reading!

Comment: Why are you reposting the identical (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436516/sturm-liouville-questions) question? Regards

Comment: Why else but to get an answer to a pressing question that will most likely just get lost in the list? ;)

Comment: I have been thinking of posting an answer, but entire books have been written on the subject and I am trying to figure out how to write something useful, pointed and that will satisfy your doubts.  So, this is not easy!

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I've tried to read them, tried video lectures on the subject but since none of them have answered my question I came here, this has been bothering me for a while now & I've tried every avenue before coming here so I appreciate whatever you can say that makes any little bit sense out of my confusion!

Comment: Are you taking a diff. eq. course now or it is a self study?

Comment: I'm just doing it on my own so yeah self study.

Comment: However, you should not post the same question twice. Getting impatient only annoys people. If your question is not getting enough attention and you think it deserves attention, you can add a bounty.